# Lombok 1.18.0 and Jackson 2.9.6 not working together

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, lombok, jackson-databind

**The deserialization is failing after the update.**

I updated my micro-service from `Spring 1.5.10.RELEASE` to `Spring 2.0.3.RELEASE` and also updated the `lombok` from `1.16.14` to `1.18.0` and `jackson-datatype-jsr310` from `2.9.4` to `2.9.6`.

The JSON string -

```
{"heading":"Validation failed","detail":"field must not be null"}
```

The Class -

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ErrorDetail {

   private final String heading;
   private final String detail;
   private String type;
}
```

Method call -

```
ErrorDetail errorDetail = asObject(jsonString, ErrorDetail.class);
```

The method used to deserialize -

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
// more imports and class defination.

private static <T> T asObject(final String str, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Error -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.foo.bar.ErrorDetail` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
at [Source: (String)"{"heading":"Validation failed","detail":"field must not be null"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Comment: Did you try to add constructer to ErrorDetail class?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Lombok stopped generating `@ConstructorProperties` on constructors with version 1.16.20 (see [changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog)), because it might break Java 9+ applications that use modules. That annotation contains the names of the constructor's parameters (they are removed when compiling the class, so that's a workaround so that the parameter names still can be retrieved at runtime). Because the annotation is now not being generated by default, Jackson cannot map the field names to the constructor parameters.

**Solution 1:**
Use a `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@Setter`, but you will loose immutability (if that's important to you).

*Update:* Just `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@Getter` (without `@Setter`) may also work (because [`INFER_PROPERTY_MUTATORS=true`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features)). In this way, you can keep the class immutable, at least from regular (non-reflective) code.

**Solution 2:**
Configure lombok to generate the annotations again, [using a `lombok.config` file](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) containing the line `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true`. (If you are using modules, make sure `java.desktop` is on your module path.) Clean and recompile after you added the `lombok.config` file.

**Solution 3:**
Use Jackson's builder support in combination with lombok's (`@Jacksonized`) `@Builder`/`@SuperBuilder`, as described in [@Randakar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51464720/lombok-1-18-0-and-jackson-2-9-6-not-working-together/55257143#55257143) to this question.

**Solution 4:**
When compiling with `javac` (of Java 8 and above), append `-parameters` to the command. This will store the parameter names of constructors and methods in the generated class files, so they can be retrieved via reflection.

Comment: Thank you. The first option did the trick. The second one did not work though.

Comment: Ad 2) Did you add the `lombok.config` to the root folder of your project? Also note that you have to clean and recompile after doing that.

Comment: @JanRieke - Could you please help me in this related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245674/ide-does-not-show-getters-and-setters-generated-by-lombok-for-a-jackson-annotate

Comment: NoArgsConstructor will not only lost immutability but also cannot check null

Comment: _Solution 1_ was not enough in my case, I had to add `@AllArgsConstructor` as well to get rid of another error _constructor ... in class ... cannot be applied to given types_. Using Java 1.8.0_265, Lombok 1.18.4, Jackson 2.9.5

Comment: Don't forget to add `@Builder` when using `@Jacksonized`.

Answer (score 18):

Edit: This answer is now a bit outdated: There is a new `@Jacksonized` annotation, from https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized, which takes care of much of the boilerplate in this answer.

---

The best way to make jackson and lombok play well together is to always make your DTO's immutable, and tell jackson to use the builder to deserialize into your objects.

Immutable objects are good idea for the simple reason that when fields cannot be modified in situ compilers can do much more aggressive optimisations.

In order to do this you need two annotations: JsonDeserialize, and JsonPojoBuilder.

Example:

```
@Builder
@Value // instead of @Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NonNull // Best practice, see below.
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ErrorDetail.ErrorDetailBuilder.class)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ErrorDetail {

   private final String heading;

   // Set defaults if fields can be missing, like this:
   @Builder.Default
   private final String detail = "default detail";

   // Example of how to do optional fields, you will need to configure
   // your object mapper to support that and include the JDK 8 module in your dependencies..
   @Builder.Default
   private Optional<String> type = Optional.empty()

   @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
   public static final class ErrorDetailBuilder {
   }
}
```

Comment: Pffew that is a lot of boiler plate annotations for a library which intends to remove boilerplate.

Comment: @ChristopheBouhier Most of the class-level annotation can be configured once when creating the Jackson ObjectMapper I assume they were included here for demonstration purpose ;-)

Comment: Actually all of this stuff has been consolidated into a single annotation: `@Jacksonized` https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized

Comment: Don't forget to add `@Builder` when using `@Jacksonized`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to deserialize a class which has final field. so u need to declare a constructor which contains final field to deserialize.

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ErrorDetail {

private final String heading;
private final String detail;
private String type;

@JsonCreator
public ErrorDetail(@JsonProperty("heading") String heading, @JsonProperty("detail") String detail) {
    this.heading = heading;
    this.detail = detail;
}
}
```

and when deserialize with mapper need to **MapperFeature.ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS** set this property **false**.

```
private static <T> T asObject(final String str, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().configure(MapperFeature.ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS,false).readValue(str, clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the above solutions, you can use `@Jacksonized` (with `@Builder`).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 4**

- Write the NoArgsConstructor yourself. This at least worked for me with lombok `1.18.8` and Jackson `2.9.9`

```
    @Builder
    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class EventDTO {

        private String id;
        private Integer isCancelled;

        private String recurringEventId;

        private String summary;
        private String description;
        private String location;
        private String startDateTime;
        private String endDateTime;

        /**
         * Make Jackson happy
         */
        public EventDTO() {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -6):

Using `@Data` annotation is bad approach, in my opinion.
Please change `@Data` to `@Getting` , `@Setter`, `@EqualsAndHashcode` and so on ..

and write here please, if it will help.

**update**

I suggest, that `@Data` create `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, and it is constructor with final fields, and without  `private String type`;

Comment: Any reason why `@Data` is bad?