# Using Lombok in immutable Request class

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, post, lombok

Welcome,

I've created simple Rest Controller:

```
 @RestController
 public class MyController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/cities", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public String getCities(@RequestBody Request request) {
        return request.getId();
    }
}
```

I want Request class to be immutable.

Is it ok to use Immutable with Lombok this way ?

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.beans.ConstructorProperties;
import java.util.List;
import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.annotations.Immutable;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Value;

@Immutable
@Value
public final class Request {

    private final String id;
    private final ImmutableList<String> lista;

    @ConstructorProperties({"id", "lista"})
    public Request(String id, List<String> lista) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lista = ImmutableList.copyOf(lista);
    }

}
```

Request JSON:

```
{
"id":"g",
"lista": ["xxx","yyy"]
}
```

Comment: According to https://www.projectlombok.org/features/Value I think it's OK

Comment: Why did you adopt that particular `@Immutable` annotation, and what do you think it does? (`@lombok.Value` is normally sufficient.)

Comment: @chrylis I think `@Immutable` is being used for documentation purposes only.

Comment: @lealceldeiro Yes, but it's being pulled out of a location that expressly isn't intended to be used externally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `lombok.config` file to your project with enabled `addConstructorProperties` property:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true
```

then Lombok will generate a `@java.beans.ConstructorProperties` annotation when generating constructors.

So you will not need to specify a constructor explicitly:

```java
@Value
public class Request {
    private String id;
    private ImmutableList<String> list;
}
```

And Jackson will be able to deserialize your object.

---

More info:

- [Lombok config](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration#overview)
- [Lombok @Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value)

Answer (score 1):

Value is immutable itself, no need for `@Immutable`. To make it Jackson-serializable use Lombok's private `@NoArgsConstructor`:

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Request {

  Integer id;
  String name;
}
```