# Jackson deserialization of a Lombok @Builder class using a mixin is not working

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, jackson-databind

This is my class:

```
@Builder
@Value
public class A {
    int id;
    String name;
    @NonNull String lastName;
}
```

The Lombok `@Builder` will add the all args constructor.

I need to deserialise a string into a POJO object.

I created the following Jackson mixin containing all three properties:

```
public abstract class AMixin {
    public AMixin(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
                  @JsonProperty("id") int id,
                  @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName) {
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    abstract String getName();

    @JsonProperty("id")
    abstract int getId();

    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    abstract String getLastName();

}
```

I deserialise like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(A.class, AMixin.class);

        String ss = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"some name\",\"lastName\":\"some name\"}\n";
        A c = mapper.readValue(ss, A.class);
    }
```

but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.bla.test.A` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":1,"name":"some name","lastName":"some name"}
"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Comment: Did you try adding @NoArgsConstructor ?

If it does not work check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51464720/lombok-1-18-0-and-jackson-2-9-6-not-working-together

Comment: @TraychoIvanov I don't want the no args constructor. My class is final and all its fields are final and must be declared in the initiation phase (constructor)

Comment: In this case you need this approach  with `@JsonDeserialize` , here there is a good example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801237/9671280

Comment: @TraychoIvanov the whole idea of mixin is to avoid adding Jackson annotation in your POJO so I'd prefer to know why my mix is not working.

Comment: @Marcoo this is pure lombok issue, believe me or not the once chance to solve it by testing the latest jackson versions otherwise you need to accept the compromise.

Comment: @TraychoIvanov I found the solution :) (no compromise on POJO being clean)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok 1.18.0 and Jackson 2.9.6 not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51464720/lombok-1-18-0-and-jackson-2-9-6-not-working-together)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

Add lombok.config file with content:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that Jackson expects a no-argument constructor or some other configured way of creating the object.  However, because of the `@Builder` annotation on `A`, the no-argument constructor is not present, only the Lombok-generated all-argument constructor `A(int id, String name, String lastName)`.

As of Lombok v1.18.14, the [`@Jacksonized`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized) annotation can be added to the class with the `@Builder` annotation, which automatically configures the builder to be used for Jackson deserialization.

```java
@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Value
public class A {
    int id;
    String name;
    @NonNull String lastName;
}
```

The Lombok [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized) for `@Jacksonized` describes this annotation in more detail:

> The `@Jacksonized` annotation is an add-on annotation for `@Builder` and `@SuperBuilder`. It automatically configures the generated builder class to be used by [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)'s deserialization. It only has an effect if present at a context where there is also a `@Builder` or a `@SuperBuilder`; a warning is emitted otherwise.
>
> [...]
>
> In particular, the annotation does the following:
>
> - Configure Jackson to use the builder for deserialization using `@JsonDeserialize(builder=_Foobar_._Foobar_Builder[Impl].class))` on the class (where *Foobar* is the name of the annotated class, and `Impl` is added for `@SuperBuilder`). (An error is emitted if such an annotation already exists.)
> - Copy Jackson-related configuration annotations (like `@JsonIgnoreProperties`) from the class to the builder class. This is necessary so that Jackson recognizes them when using the builder.
> - Insert `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")` on the generated builder class to override Jackson's default prefix "with". If you configured a different prefix in lombok using `setterPrefix`, this value is used. If you changed the name of the `build()` method using using `buildMethodName`, this is also made known to Jackson.
> - For `@SuperBuilder`, make the builder implementation class package-private.

---

Note: This issue has nothing to do with the usage of a mixin, which can be verified by moving Jackson configuration from the mixin to the class itself and observing that the issue is still present.