# Lombok - Using both `@Value` and `@NoArgsConstructor` on a pojo

Tags: lombok

Is it possible with additional configuration etc to have both `@Value` and `@NoArgsConstructor` on a pojo. Something like below.

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestClass implements Serializable {

    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;

}
```

For the above class intelij gives compilation error - `Variable 'x', 'y', 'z' might not have been initialized` etc.

I will appreciate if you can give a working pojo as example.

Work Arounds -

1. I know i can use something like below as a work around-

   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @Getter
   public class TestClass implements Serializable {

   ```
        private String x;
        private String y;
        private String z;

    }
   ```
2. I need the @NoArgsConstructor as jackson needs it. I could find other ways to handle immutable classes with jackson - [1](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-immutable-objects) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61469090/4820101). **But would still prefer to handle it through lombok if it's possible.**

Comment: Jackson does _not_ need a default/no-args constructor, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51464720/lombok-1-18-0-and-jackson-2-9-6-not-working-together/51465038#51465038

Comment: @JanRieke, thanks +1. Plz see my edit. I could see other ways to deal with problem.. but I still want to explore a solution based on `lombok`.

Comment: The link above is a solution with Lombok.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `@Jacksonized`, as shown in [@Dusan.czh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69371859/10231374).

In your case the class would look like this:

```java
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.extern.jackson.Jacksonized;

@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Value
public class TestClass {
    String x;
    String y;
    String z;
}
```

`@Value` already marks non-static, package-local fields private and final, so there is no need for private access modifier.

Comment: from lombok docs - `@Jacksonized was introduced as experimental feature in lombok v1.18.14` - i have to update to this version.. +1